# TPM not offering to unlock C:\ drive automatically at boot up: "Chose how to unlock your drive at startup" (Flash drive or PW)

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

I'm trying to enable BitLocker on a Win10 (Dell Optiplex 7040) desktop. The issue I'm facing is that I need the drive to auto-unlock at startup since it will often be used remotely via RDP (rebooting would render the machine unusable since no one would be there to unlock it):

[image: TPM-not-working]

[image: TPM recognized by OS]

[image: Get-TPM command results]

[image: All GPO settings at default / not-configured]

- The Windows 10 license is Professional
- The TPM is recognized by the OS (verified by view in MMC.exe and the PS `Get-TPM` command)
- All GPO settings are at default

What should I do here, **reset/clear the TPM?** I will have to wait until someone is at the site to do that (I just have remote access to the machine currently).

Comment: Is the drive you want to protect with Bitlocker the system drive? Auto unlocking a non-system disk without password or other user interaction are, as far as I know only possible if the system drive is Bitlocker protected via TPM. If your system is part of a domain make sure that the domain GPO does not disallow certain Bitlocker modes (you can use `gpresult.exe` to check).

Comment: Thank you, @Robert. This machine is indeed Domain joined, but only the Default Domain Policy is being applied and there are no BL settings configured in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - this machine was setup with Legacy Boot. I've switched it to **use UEFI with secure boot** and BitLocker is working properly (with the TPM storing the start-up key) now. I used this to convert the boot loader:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx